# New to programming, using Python for automation

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm new to programming and wanted to learn python for some automation. I used Selenium to record type and key strokes on a web form. This form will detect if you've signed up before so each time I run the test the first and last name, email address and street address need to be unique. I'm trying to generate a random email address in the email and conform email fields. I've fixed a lot of other issues but getting the below error when trying to run my script

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jeff.hall/Desktop/PythonProjects/PythonAutomation.py", line 29, in test_untitled_test_case
    email = self.generate_email()
  File "C:/Users/jeff.hall/Desktop/PythonProjects/PythonAutomation.py", line 26, in generate_email
    return prefix + random_part + '@' + domain
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'UntitledTestCase' and 'str'

Below is a portion of the code giving me issues

```
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    self.base_url = "https://www.katalon.com/"
    self.verificationErrors = []
    self.accept_next_alert = True

def generate_email(prefix='huks214+', domain='gmail.com'):
 random_part = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits)
    for _ in range(10))
 return prefix + random_part + '@' + domain

def test_untitled_test_case(self):
    email = self.generate_email()


    driver.get("http://profile.benihana.com/registration/")
    driver.find_element_by_id("First_Nm").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("First_Nm").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("First_Nm").send_keys("gsg")
    driver.find_element_by_id("Last_Nm").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("Last_Nm").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("Last_Nm").send_keys("rtyrtuyt")
    driver.find_element_by_id("Email_Address").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("Email_Address").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("Email_Address").send_keys(email)
    confirm_email = driver.find_element_by_id("Cnfm_Email_Address")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These methods are all part of a `class` - presumably called `UntitledTestCase`.  As such they all need `self` as the first argument.

You have:

```
def generate_email(prefix='huks214+', domain='gmail.com'):
```

Class methods are normally called with the class instance passed in as the first argument. So when called, `prefix` will end being the class instance, rather than the default string, hence the error message about `UntitledTestCase`.

This is why you usually need to have `self` as the first argument. However, since you aren't going to use it, a better option is to decorate the method with `@staticmethod`, which marks the class as not requiring `self` so it won't be passed in.

```
@staticmethod
def generate_email(prefix='huks214+', domain='gmail.com'):
```